# how to get space seperate array value and store it in an array? example: input in form 10 20 30 ouput:a[0]=10 a[2]=20 a[3]=30

Tags: c

how to get space seperated integer value in single line and store it in array variable:

```
input:
10 20 30
```

how can i store it in

```
a[0],a[1],a[3]
```

My code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 0, j, arr[100], n, x;
    while(i < 100 && scanf("%d", &arr[i]) == 1)
    {
        i++;
    }

    for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arr[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember to describe the problem you are facing

Comment: you need to read [how to ask a query on stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There is no apparent need to tag this C++. Please avoid using multiple language tags when it is uncalled for. That being said, it is unclear what you are asking, what is the logic behind "10 20 30 ouput:a[0]=10 a[2]=20 a[3]=30"?

Comment: Well: what's the problem of [your code](http://ideone.com/z9pcFd)

Comment: I need to get input in the form of space seperated integers like 10 12 13.. and then i have to store each integer value in an array. this is my task.But i am getting it using above code.can you help me to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your problem is that your program doesn't carry on after input like:

```
10 20 30
```

The reason is that the program gets stuck in the `scanf` waiting for more input.

You can make the program carry on by input like:

```
10 20 30 x
```

but that is probably not what you want.

Instead you can read a whole line using `fgets` and the parse the line.

Something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
  char line[1000];
  int i = 0, j, arr[100];

  fgets(line, 1000, stdin);
  char* p = line;
  while(i < 100 && sscanf(p, "%d", &arr[i]) == 1)
  {
    i++;

    // Remove leading spaces
    while(*p == ' ') ++p;

    // Advance to next space
    p = strchr(p, ' ');
    if (p == NULL)
    {
      // All input handled
      break;
    }
  }

  for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
  {
    printf("%d\n", arr[j]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code and the reading part actually works. I assume, however, your problem is getting out of the reading loop...

Try with a smaller array (let's say of size 3) and input numbers accordingly and you'll see; other variant: leave your big array, input three numbers and then xyz (which can't be evaluated by your scanf expression).

Problem is that if you press enter, scanf simply reads a new-line character, which is considered as any other whitespace, so scanf expects further input (try again with array of size 3 and enter three numbers, each being terminated by pressing enter and you'll see).

So you would have to scan for new line character explicitly, but that gets ugly quickly. You're better of by reading one line at once and then scan the input buffer using sscanf:

```
char buffer[256];
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

int i = 0, j, arr[100];
char* b = buffer;
int n = 0;
while(i < 100 && sscanf(b, "%d%n", &arr[i], &n) == 1)
{
    b += n;
    i++;
}
for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    printf("%d\n", arr[j]);
}
```

A variant without the line buffer could look like this:

```
int i = 0, j, arr[3];
while(i < 3 && scanf("%d", &arr[i]) == 1)
{
    char c;
    do
    {
        scanf("%c", &c);
    }
    while(isspace(c) && c != '\n');
    ++i;
    if(c == '\n')
        break;
    ungetc(c, stdin);
}
for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    printf("%d\n", arr[j]);
}
```